# Inverse Laplace transform of $\tan ^{-1} (2/s)$

Tags: inverse, laplace-transform

i am trying to compute inverse Laplace transform of  function  = $\tan ^{-1} (2/s)$

Comment: **Hint:** Differentiate $\arctan (2/s)$ with respect to $s$.

Comment: What do you mean by $\tan^{-1}(2/s)$? Do you mean $\arctan(2/s)$ or $1/\tan(2/s)$?

Answer (score 3):

‎$${\cal L}\Big(\frac{\sin2t}{t}\Big)=\int_s^\infty\frac{2}{s^2+4}~ds=\arctan\frac{s}{2}\Big|_s^\infty=\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan\frac{s}{2}=\arctan\frac{2}{s}$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $$\mathcal{L}(tf(t))=-\frac{d}{ds}(F(s)).$$

Comment: Is the answer is sin 2t .. ?

Comment: @Sebastian No, you are missing one important step.

Comment: I haven't done the calculations. But it should be some expression similar to $\frac{\sin(2t)}{t}$.

Comment: Thanks thats the right answer..  Sin (2t)/t